# Position CGRect in the center for text output

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the following code:

```
let number = cluster.memberAnnotations.count
displayPriority = .defaultHigh
image = textToImage(
    drawText: "\(number)",
    inImage: UIImage(named: "map-pin-full-cluster-1")!
        .withTintColor(.blue, renderingMode: . alwaysTemplate)
        .resizeWith(
            newSize: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)), atPoint: CGPointMake(14.5, 3.5)
)
```

Which outputs the following look on the map:

[image]

Here is a function that I am using to assist me:

```
func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

Problem:
When the number ends up going into double digit, it isn't contained within the circle, how can I format my code so that I can center a number based on a CRect or other call?

**[image]**:

Comment: Instead of `let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)`, I'd use `let rect = let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: point.y), size: image.size)` //here image size is too big, it should be only the "circle part"), and use `NSParagraphStyleAttribute`, to make the text centered.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, I am getting closer - I have never used `NSParagraphStyleAttribute`. so I will look into this. Your suggestion worked well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working thanks to @Larme's guidance:

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

let textFontAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraph,
    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
```

Define a `NSMutableParagraphStyle()` and set the `paragraphStyle` to it's attribute.